# HTML not loading linked Css type sheet

Tags: html, css

index.html file contains this

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> <link>
  <nav class="header">
 <img     src="/Users/DeMarcus/Desktop/DevProjects/Websites/CodeCademy/p.4 Datsomo/Resources/images/pattern.jpg" alt="">
<h1>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</h1>
```

i Have this link which I'm using to connect my html file to my css file. Its just that when i load my page it appears without any css.

I know I've written my css correctly and used classes to identify my div containers. Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong here?

css file contains this

```
header{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: khaki;
  text-align: center;`.

}
```

Comment: either change `<nav class="header">` to `<header class="header">` or use `.header` as the CSS selector, not `header`

Comment: @MichaelCoker i don't know why the editor didn't pick this up i used .header as my selector.

Comment: Ah. If you look at the end of your css, you have a `\`.` - I'm assuming that's the `.` that's missing when you copied/pasted

Comment: What you have works fine. Are index.html and style.css in the same directory? And do you have any errors in your browser console? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/pwpdKP (I also cleaned up your HTML. You need to close `<nav>` and remove the stray `<link>` - a `link` doesn't need to be closed)

Comment: @MichaelCoker  
i have them saved in the same folder. But whenever i load it in safari i see the page without css. I applied the tweaks you've made but still i don't see any css in safari when i open my html file.

Comment: @DemarcusEdwards first of all, make sure your html file and css file are at same level. If not you need to mention path for css file like `href="/resources/css/style.css"`. Second of all that's not how you set css for class. You need to use `.` before header as it is defined as class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

`<link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

By adding ./ before style.css, you are explicitly telling the browser that your file is in the same folder.

Also, check the case of the css file. I can see that in the img src you have used capital characters and spaces. Try to avoid spaces and capitals in file names as servers are usually case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the css is getting loaded.
To check this right click on the page -> view page source. Click the link in the `href` attribute to see if you get your css file.

If you can see your css file you probably have a syntax error in your css file.

If you can't see your css file, you need to change the link to your css file.

To link to your css file use this syntax:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

It also seems you need to change the code in your css file to something like this:

```
.header {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: khaki;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Note I added a `.` before the header, since it is a class.

Another note: you should close your `<nav>` tag.